# Создать регулярное выражение для линтера

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Очень плохо знаком с регулярными выражениями и нуждаюсь в вашей помощи.

Нужно регулярное выражение, под которое подошла бы данная строка:

```
_("qwe %s asd" % "zxc")
```

Вместо букв может быть любое содержание.

Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Сам всегда ломаю голову на регулярными ворожениями. Надеюсь поможет этот сервис https://regex101.com/

Comment: Ничего не понял. Нужны нормальные примеры и нормальное описание.

Comment: `.*` — ваша строка отлично подойдёт. и `_("qwe %s asd" % "zxc")`, разумеется, тоже подойдёт под вашу строку.